# Ip doesn't change when switching networks, although automatic ip is set. Cause of the issue known

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip, internet-connection

I have two routers at my house. Both of them have DCHP server enabled. One of them is 192.168.1.1 and gives addresses from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.32 The other one is 192.168.1.50 and gives addresses from 192.168.1.51 to 192.168.1.99

The problem is that I only have internet access in one because my IP is 192.168.1.7, and when I switch to the other one, the IP remains 192.168.1.7, even though I have automatically get a IP address in Ipv4. When I manually change my IP to one in the range allowed by the router, I can browse the internet. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: My guess is that either Windows isn't requesting a new IP (because it has determined the IP is not in use and the subnet hasn't changed), or Windows is requesting a renewal, and as the IP is outside of the range allocated to the second DHCP server, it does not NAQ it.  I suggest trying a different subnet on the one of the routers.

Comment: Which netmask are you using? 255.255.255.224?